# jquery scrolltop stay position after response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote a code to view the chat history. Everything works fine, but I realized that. When you scroll up the div to view the history, old posts are displayed at a time. I've added this code `$("#messages").scrollTop(200);` to be able to continue scrolling, but this should not be. When you want to view old messages in apps like whatsapp or facebook, you can continue to scroll up for viewing old messages.

What am I supposed to do to stay position after response?

Here is **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/NVQZxz?editors=1010)** page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var logDown = $(".chatContainer");
  logDown.animate({ scrollTop: logDown.prop("scrollHeight") }, 0);
  var messages = ''; // New Posts are in demo
  var scrollLoading = true;
  $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight);
  $("#messages").on("scroll", function() {
    if (scrollLoading && $("#messages").scrollTop() == 0) {
      $("#messages").prepend(messages);
      $("#messages").scrollTop(200);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: seems to work fine for me, i can scroll up as much i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now I understood, i solved it by subtracting the old-height from the new height and set this "old-position" as scrolltop

```
var old_height,new_height;
$("#messages").on("scroll", function() {
    if (scrollLoading && $("#messages").scrollTop() == 0) {
      old_height = $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight;
      $("#messages").prepend(messages);      
      new_height = $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight;
      $("#messages").scrollTop(new_height - old_height); 
    }
  });
```

works optimal for me

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem you don't want to scroll to the top of the messages at every batch of prepends.

I managed to pull a version without jQuery and using `window.requestAnimationFrame` for good scroll performance.

Just my $0.02 on the problem.

```js
var container = document.querySelector("#messages");
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
container.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = e.target.scrollTop;
  var ticking;

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      if (last_known_scroll_position == 0) {
        var delta = e.target.scrollHeight;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
          var message = document.createElement("DIV");
          message.textContent = "Message Here";
          message.classList.add("message", "red");
          e.target.prepend(message);
        }
        delta = e.target.scrollHeight - delta;
        e.target.scrollTop = delta;
        ticking = false;
      }
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

```css
DIV.chatContainer {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.message {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.red {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="chatContainer" id="messages">
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE</div>
    <div class="message">Message HERE last</div>
  </div>
</div>
```